# Подскажите,пожалуйста. Какой поставить знак? Или же я не правильно составил?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые, синтаксис

Теперь время планов, а их у меня хватает(?)даже не знаю с чего начать.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае в ваше предложение является сложным (то есть имеет несколько грамматических основ).

Но это предложение ещё интересно тем, что эти основы "неполные". Я имею в виду то, что первая основа состоит только из подлежащего, вторая - только из сказуемого, третья и четвёртая - тоже только из сказуемого.

> Теперь **время** планов, а их у меня **хватает**(?)даже **не знаю** (?) с чего начать.

Но если вам непривычно видеть основы только из подлежащего или только из сказуемого, то можно изменить предложение так (расстановка знаков препинания не изменится):

> Теперь **настало время** планов, а их у меня **хватает**(?) я даже **не знаю** (?) с чего я должен **начать**.

Поскольку ваше предложение сложное, все его части должны быть разграничены запятыми. Но тут ещё один подвоный корень: в предложении ещё есть одно тире (оно будет стоять между второй и третьей основой). Здесь работает это правило:

> Тире ставится между предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если второе предложение заключает в себе результат или вывод из того, о чем говорится в первом, например:
> Хвалы приманчивы – как их не пожелать?

В общем, ваше предложение с правильно расставленными знаками препинания выглядит так:

> Теперь время планов, а их у меня хватает - даже не знаю, с чего начать.